# Font Awesome: Stacked and Fixed Width

Tags: css, font-awesome

How can I have stacked icons and apply fixed width to both icons (or to the stack itself)?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p>
    <span class="fa-stack text-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-2x fa-stop"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-exclamation fa-inverse"></i>
    </span> Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

The above example does not result in a fixed width icon. Adding `fa-fw` to the span class does not resolve the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @raphael - I posted an answer below

Comment: Awesome thanks! I edited your answer to add a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that a newer version of Font Awesome fixes this issue. I am using v4.4 below.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack text-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-2x fa-stop"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-exclamation fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>&nbsp; Some text
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-anchor"></i>
            </span>&nbsp; Anchor
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack text-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-2x fa-stop"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-exclamation fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>&nbsp; Some text
    </a>
    <br>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-anchor"></i>
                </span>&nbsp; Anchor
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order for the rest of the icons in the list-group to appear with the same fixed width they have to be stacked behind an empty icon.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it but what if you try :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p>
    <span class="fa-stack text-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-2x fa-stop" style="font-size:20px"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-exclamation fa-inverse" style="font-size:20px"></i>
    </span> Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

... and adjust the values to fit the width attempted.

If it works, you could overwrite the original styles `.fa-stop`, `.fa-exclamation` ... directly in your CSS stylesheet. Maybe you will have to use `!important` hack.

Comment: I didn't want to accept this as an answer because it required inline styles. Thanks for your input though. :)

Comment: @whargrove:  See the end of my post. I said that you can override the original classes to avoid inline-styles.